# Why does SSH requires but doesn't care about host address when using SOCKET file?

Tags: ssh, openssh

If there is a socket file, SSH can multiplex the connection. In order to create a socket, we use:

```
ssh -M -S /tmp/hello me@example.com
```

For example, in order to run a command on the server by using this socket file:

```
ssh -S /tmp/hello example.com uname -a
```

SSH requires `host` field while using `-S /tmp/hello`, but doesn't care. The following has the same effect:

```
ssh -S /tmp/hello whocares uname -a
```

Why does SSH require, but doesn't care about the hostname?

This behaviour of SSH (sharing the connection described with the socket file (`/tmp/hello`) and ignoring any credentials) is both what I wanted and what I expected. But **requiring the hostname** is somewhat confusing.

Question comes to this point: Would I ever have a problem if I use this command as follows:

```
ssh -S /path/to/my-first-host.socket example.com .... # expect connecting first host
ssh -S /path/to/my-second-host.socket example.com .... # expect connecting second host
ssh -S /path/to/my-third-host.socket example.com .... # expect connecting third host
```

Comment: Presumably so it can apply configuration from `~/.ssh/config`, etc. matching on hostnames?

Comment: No, there is no such configuration option. Can you try the same steps by yourself?

Answer (score 3):

You can specify additional configuration based on hostnames to SSH via `~/.ssh/config`, `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`, etc. While the hostname itself might not matter when connecting over a control socket, these options do get applied, where applicable:

```
$ cat ~/.ssh/config
Host foo
    LocalForward 8080 localhost:9000
$ ssh -fMS /tmp/hello localhost sleep 1d
muru@localhost's password:
$ ssh -fS /tmp/hello foo sleep 1d & sudo lsof -i :8080
[1] 6971
[sudo] password for muru:
COMMAND  PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
ssh     6859 muru    8u  IPv6 148286      0t0  TCP ip6-localhost:http-alt (LISTEN)
ssh     6859 muru    9u  IPv4 148287      0t0  TCP localhost:http-alt (LISTEN)
```

Clearly SSH applied the port forwarding rules I specified in `~/.ssh/config`, even though it used the control socket. In fact, the port forwarding is done by the process which created the socket:

```
$ pgrep -fa hello
6859 ssh -fMS /tmp/hello localhost sleep 1d
6971 ssh -fS /tmp/hello foo sleep 1d
```

Comment: This is one of the use cases, but I would not say it is the intended nor it does not answer the question, why it is connecting to the same host when you write different one.

Comment: Sorry, this answer is not related with the question as we are interested in why it requires and then ignores the hostname.

Comment: @ceremcem This answer is proof that it does not ignore the hostname.

Comment: Hmm. You say "SSH will connect to the server which the socket file points regardless of the hostname you passed, but if you pass an appropriate hostname which is in `~/.ssh/config`, it will apply these settings too", right? This makes "a little bit" sense.

Comment: Your answer states something useful, something right, but it is unclear and very hard to understand. There is an output with an unknown command, the output of that unknown command is totally unrelated with above commands **if you don't know `http-alt` is an alias to `8080`**

Comment: @ceremcem @ceremcem `lsof -i :<port>` is a pretty common Linux command to see what is listening on a given port. The port is right there in the command, you don't even need to know anything about `http-alt`.

Comment: A-ha! I did't catch it. (Why don't you put that `lsof` command on the next line?)

Comment: Also, If you state "In order not to miss to apply any configuration from `~/.ssh/config`, it **does require** the hostname", that would be the correct answer.

Comment: @Jakuje it's never been guaranteed that the host argument you give is what SSH will use for the server hostname. That's one of the most trivial customisations possible in ssh_config using the `Hostname` option. It's hardly surprising therefore that that it connected to a different hostname when you gave another option that affects the actual server being connected to.

Answer (score 2):

> Why do SSH requires but doesn't care the hostname?

Because the control sockets SHOULD be based on the hostname you are connecting to, as described in the manual page for `ssh_config`:

> `ControlPath`
>
> Specify the path to the control socket used for connection sharing as described in the ControlMaster section above or the string none to disable connection sharing.  Arguments to ControlPath
>   may use the tilde syntax to refer to a user's home directory or the tokens described in the TOKENS section.  **It is recommended that any ControlPath used for opportunistic connection sharing
>   include at least %h, %p, and %r (or alternatively %C)** and be placed in a directory that is not writable by other users.*  This ensures that shared connections are uniquely identified.

If you do not follow these recommendations and try to connect to different host with the same socket, `ssh` finds the existing socket and uses it regardless the written hostname.

## To the edited question:

> Would I ever have a problem if I use this command as follows ...
>
> ```
> ssh -S /path/to/my-first-host.socket example.com .... # expect connecting first host
> ssh -S /path/to/my-second-host.socket example.com .... # expect connecting second host
> ssh -S /path/to/my-third-host.socket example.com .... # expect connecting third host
> ```

Yes. It is not enforced/used now, but you are clearly using undocumented/undefined behavior, which can change at some future release without any notice.

Comment: "Because" section of the answer does not point out "why doesn't it care" part of the question. Moreover, recommendation is unrelated with our case as our problem is not related with identifying socket files uniquely. Also see edit to the question.

Comment: Doesn't it? Well ... there could be some check in the mux API, but it would make it more complicated. There is SHOULD instead of MUST so the check is not there and it is your responsibility to know what are you doing. .... Is it unrelated? If it would be named according to the recommendation, the ssh would not find an existing socket and would connect using normal TCP. If it finds one, it expects it is the one it should be using and it does it.

Comment: I didn't ever read that recommendation before, but [I have been naming socket files](https://github.com/aktos-io/aktos-bash-lib/blob/367da5fe23fc6559f249a4ed80ed4ab8357025f2/ssh-functions.sh#L13) in the way they recommended. But still, it isn't related with our problem since we are not interested in "Why do we connect to same server even though we pass different hostnames but the same socket file" type of question. We are interested in "Why SSH requires something to ignore later".

Comment: I explained you why it does what it does. It requires hostname because you need an hostname if you want to connect somewhere (isn't it?). If you want to know why it is "ignored", ask the developers.

Answer (score 1):

The section covering `ssh -S` in the man page for `ssh` refers readers to the `ControlMaster` and `ControlPath` sections of the `ssh_config`(5) man page. In turn it states,

> **ControlMaster**  Enables the sharing of multiple sessions over a single network connection. [...] These sessions will try to reuse the master instance's network connection rather than initiating new ones, *but will fall back to connecting normally if the control socket does not exist, or is not listening.*

So, in summary, `ssh` uses the control socket if it can, but falls back to a normal connection otherwise. To achieve a normal connection the target hostname is required.

As an aside, the recommendation for a `ControlPath` is that its name (template) should include at least the target hostname (`%h`) so that different target hosts receive different Control Path values. If you just blindly use an arbitrary and different hostname value for each connection this recommendation cannot be applied.